# Google sheets Create a new rows in range of columns based on split of data in one column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet that contains transactions with date, type, amount etc. The transaction type may be re-investment, deposit etc. When there is a 're-investment' transaction, I want to create a virtual range by inserting a new row duplicating the data of the re-investment row but with a type of 'payment'. I will then run a query using importrange against this new virtual data range from another sheet to produce a report.

[Here is an abstraction of my requirements. If there is a transaction-type = “DR”, create/insert a matching transaction of type = “CR”These are highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqfwn.jpg)

| Date | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **BEFORE** |  |  |
| 30/01/2024 | DR | $10.00 |
| 29/01/2024 | TR | $20.00 |
| 27/01/2024 | WD | $30.00 |
| 24/01/2024 | DR | $40.00 |
| 20/01/2024 |  |  |
| 30/01/2024 | IN | $100.00 |
|  |  |  |
| **AFTER** |  |  |
| 30/01/2024 | DR | $10.00 |
| 30/01/2024 | CR | $10.00 |
| 29/01/2024 | TR | $20.00 |
| 27/01/2024 | WD | $30.00 |
| 30/01/2024 | CR | $40.00 |
| 20/01/2024 | DR | $50.00 |
| 20/01/2024 |  |  |
| 30/01/2024 | IN | $100.00 |

I have tried using the split function against a modified 'type' column where some cells originally "re-investment" are now "re-investment,payment" (eg comma separated) in an array formula to create a virtual column of the split and all other transaction types.

I need help suggestions to merge this virtual column with the data of the other columns to create a virtual range that can be queried.

This issue is similar to: [Split text data into one column for several rows in Google Sheets/Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620383/split-text-data-into-one-column-for-several-rows-in-google-sheets-excel)
but there is more than one column of original data in my case.
Thanks

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

Comment: `I need help suggestions to` This is not a good decription of a problem and I think it is off-topic for this forum. However, I think you have made a basic mistake by thinking that this involves a "virtual column" achievable by a formula. I suggest that it is a "real" transaction that will require an apps-script solution. The description of the process for managing a reinvestment is unclear; I suggest that you create a manual proto-type to establish exactly how the initial transaction AND the reinvestment can be tracked, balanced and reported. This may assist you to identify a specific problem.

Comment: The Help instructions are pretty clear about this: **DO NOT post images of [] data, [], etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.** `Please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.`

Comment: @Tedinoz. Point taken. I could not figure out how to present my data like that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620383/split-text-data-into-one-column-for-several-rows-in-google-sheets-excel.

Comment: @KimPrisk I can't see how this problem is like [Split text data into one column for several rows in Google Sheets/Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72620383/1330560). hat question creates lines by splitting existing comma-separated cells; you don't have any comma-separated cells, and you want to **add* a line. OTOH, I suggest that the question is more like [Adding an additional row of data based on condition - Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71685645/1330560} - this involves _creating_ new lines based on certain assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell E2. Insert  column headers manually.

`=sort({query({A2:C7},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 is not null"); QUERY(QUERY({A2:C},  "select Col1,'CR', Col3  where Col1 is not null and Col2 = 'DR'"), "offset 1", 0)},3,1)`

---

**BEFORE**

[image: before]

---

**AFTER**

[image: after]

---

**Logic**

- "create the virtual rows"

  - `QUERY` - create row with Type = "CR" where Col2 = 'DR'
- " add the existing rows"

  - `QUERY` - stack the virtual row query and a query of all rows.
- sort the results

  - SORT - sort the results by Amount (Col3) ascending